# R: linear regression: very small coefficient and R-squared but significant P values

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients

I've got a very small coefficient (-0.04) and R-squared (0.028) but a significant P value (<0.0001). My question is:

- Is my result still meaningful?
- How to interpret it?

The result is from a linear regression model in a big database in R. 
The independent variable (`B`) has more than 200 values, whereas the dependent variable (`A`) has 13 values.

The potential correlation is below:
[image: A vs B]

So, I ran a linear regression model between `A` and `B` and the result is:

```
>mod1<-lm(A~B)

        Call:
        lm(formula = A ~ B)

         Residuals:
             Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
         -63.174 -11.816  -1.651  10.184 118.001 

         Coefficients:
                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
         (Intercept) 132.274547   0.303723 435.511  < 2e-16 ***
         B            -0.036675   0.009052  -4.052 5.13e-05 ***
         ---
        Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

        Residual standard error: 18.52 on 8093 degrees of freedom
           (123 observations deleted due to missingness)
        Multiple R-squared:  0.002024,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.001901 
        F-statistic: 16.42 on 1 and 8093 DF,  p-value: 5.134e-05
```

As you can see, the coefficient of `B` is only -0.03 and adjusted R squared is only 0.1% but with a p value <0.0001. Is my result reasonable and countable? Surely, my database is larger (8000 records) and even a very small effect size will show a significant P value. But how would I interpret this?

Comment: "whereas the dependent variable (A) has 13 values" Does that mean A is not a continuous variable? Is B a continuous variable? How do you define "reasonable and countable"?

Comment: In your plot it looks like B has 13 values and A has more than 200 different values instead of the other way around.

Comment: It is very hard to think of any real situation, where this small an effect is going to play any role in prediction. The effect is tiny, so tiny, that you can not spot it with the eye, yet with a large n you can proove, that the slightest trend exists. Is it meaningful? Does it tell the science community anything? That can not be answered without knowing what you examined an know more about your topic of study. Likely? No!

Comment: The R^2 and p-values depend on assumptions of normality which are violated here, so I wouldn't place any stock in the result.

Comment: @Paul those depend on assumptions of normality of the residuals.

Comment: @Firebug, sure, but the residuals aren't normally distributed here.

Comment: For every unit increase in B you predict A to go down by 0.03. Since B has a range of 100 you can say that is a change of 3 in A for 100 change in B. Whether that is worth bothering about is a scientific question and depends on your situation.

Comment: To add my own perspective, when you build a model (regression, t-test, whatever) with a large enough data set, say, 10,000 observations, you're bound to get very low p-values. However, you'll have to focus on your effect sizes. If your adj-R^2 is really low, then your model is a poor fit. With large enough data sets, it is really easy to get significantly low p-values.

Comment: Thanks everyone. If I understand right, very low P value only detects whether there is any correlation between A and B and it is often influenced by large sample size. In my case, it would be more reasonable to check R-squared. Well, that also leaves me an very interesting question here: does it always like that? So if sample size is large (>100000) with significant P value, do we always need to check R-squared? If R-squared is too small, it is more likely the large sample size maximise the effect. Well, how to interpret this is up to  real life cases (either correlated or not at all).

Comment: You can interpret a small effect as a small effect. What sort of explanation are you looking for or expecting with this question?

Answer (score 6):

The coefficient of -0.036 for B means that A decreases by 0.036 every unit increase of B. The R-squared of 0.028 means that by knowing B you could explain 2,8% of the variance in A. This is generally considered small, but it depends on your applications.

Now, about the meaningfulness of these results. There are two different things here: significance and effect-size. The p-value says something about the significance of the result and the R-squared says something about the effect-size.

If the result is *meaningful* depends on the effect-size and on what you think is large. If you find this effect large, than it is meaningful. If you think it's rather small and you would have expected it to be larger, than it is not meaningful.

If the result is probably *different* from the null hypothesis is expressed by the p-value. In this case the significance says that it is rather unlikely (tiny, tiny probability) that this data was generated from an underlying distribution where there is no relation between A and B. If you want to conclude that the slope of A on B is different from 0 than this p-value might be relevant. If you are looking for meaningful effects, than you should first look at the effect-size.

Answer (score 0):

Your result is meaningful. If what you want a "larger" coefficient to make you more comfortable, you can simple standardize input (x, y) such that they have mean 0 and unit norm. Then, your regression coefficient should be large.

Albeit, you can't do anything about R^2. Assume running a univariate regression, R2=correl(x, y)^2. A low R2 just means low correl between your predictor and target