# how to calculate critical values of Pearson's correlation coefficient for a large data set containing rows greater than 5000?

Tags: statistical-significance

I have gone through various materials online but all the formulas were for small values of n(number of rows) say like 100,120 etc.But my problem is to calculate the critical value 
for values of n(number of rows).Using the tests like t-tests etc are givings unexpected results like the relation which is not actually significant becomes significant.

so how to calculate it?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "Using the tests like t-tests etc are givings unexpected results like the relation which is not actually significant becomes significant" ... how can you tell it's "not actually significant"? Can you show an example?

Comment: yeah...see i have got correlation between two variables as 0.149(approx). But the p value in less than 0.00001 which satisfies the condition of being significant i.e.. p<0.05 .so by testing its actually significant but in reality that should not be.

Comment: You dodged the question of how you could tell it should not be significant. Your problem is simply that you misunderstand statistical significance, I think. If $n$ was just 5000 (rather than even larger) an approximate Z-value would be $0.149 \sqrt{5000}$ which is $>10$ so the p value should be very very tiny indeed, quite a bit less than $10^{-23}$

Comment: exactly..it was like  even less in powers of 10^(-26).

Comment: Yes that's about right; I was just giving a rough bound (out that far the precise p-value is pretty meaningless because the calculation would change dramatically with a tiny change in the assumptions). I have a post about ready to go, but I'll just double check for a duplicate

Comment: Somewhat related but as near as I could find: a regression question with a large sample ($n$ is about 9000) and a small squared correlation ($r^2 =0.002024$) which is significant at typical significance levels [R: linear regression: very small coefficient and R-squared but significant P values](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245039/r-linear-regression-very-small-coefficient-and-r-squared-but-significant-p-val). Since it may not be immediately clear to all why it's relevant, I will hold off closing this as a duplicate of that one, at least for now. I may find a better one.

Comment: have u got a better one?

Comment: Spending time looking for duplicates is actually [your job](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (see the part about 'search and research'), and is supposed to happen before you post your question. If I do it for you, it happens when I can fit it in. If you want to help out a little you could explain in what way the linked post doesn't suffice.

Comment: Oh, I found an almost exact duplicate of this question after all ... *you* posted it. Fix your questions, don't repost them. Feel free to incorporate any clarifying information from here.

Comment: I have answered there.