# What does small R squared mean in linear regression

Tags: regression, r-squared

I'm applying linear regression on. problem and getting very small R squared, e.g. 0.087 and adjusted R squared 0.057. This is very small for R squared. What does this mean for my regression? Does it mean the variables do not have enough predictive power?

Comment: Have you looked at other answers on the website?  Example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/245067/54725.  $R^2$ is simply the fraction of variance in your output variable that's explained by your predictor variables.  Whether it's sufficient or not really depends on your application.

Comment: A useful model should explain some considerable fraction of the dependent variable's variance, and your R-squared value of 0.087 indicates that the current model explains approximately 8.7 percent of the dependent data variance and indicates the fitting results are not effectively modeling the data. In much of the professional statistical literature that discusses this type of modeling result, the term most often used to describe such an outcome is "poopy-doopy".